# How to access another projects connection string from my WCF service in same solutions

Tags: c#, wcf, web-config, connection-string

I have my application and WCF service in same Solution.
I have written a property in a class(in the App) to get the ConnectionString from `Web.Config` of App. 
Now need to access the same connection string in my WCF Service, but I have another `Web.Config` in my WCF Service(where all the bindings are defined). But I need to access the connection string of app.

```
//This is the connection string of App, where I am retrieving it in a common class. 
public static readonly string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
```

Comment: You can access it with the same name..Net will look up the configuration key in the config file of the application which started the app domain.If it is not working,add a reference for System.Configuration.

Comment: I tried doing that too, but the problem here is, I wont load the class(which has the connection string) but I want the connectionstring from that class, foolish may be, but give me any other alternative.

Comment: Add your connection string to a new class, call it lets say MyConfig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the connection string from another `web.config`. In asp.net project can have two web.config file in different directory.

Note : If the connection strings have the same "name", then the one in the directory will override the one in the root folder.

Add the `Namespace` to your class and access/read the web.config file connection string as it is. Before that Add the same Web.config file in to some other file Directory in your project.

Answer (score 0):

The right answer is "Don't do it, Add the connection string the the config of the edge project"

If you insist on messing with the devil, use something similar to this (change it to your needs):

```
var fileMap = new ConfigurationFileMap("configFilePath");
var configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedMachineConfiguration(fileMap);
var sectionGroup = configuration.GetSectionGroup("connectionStrings "); // This is the section group name, change to your needs
var section = (ClientSettingsSection)sectionGroup.Sections.Get("MyTarget.Namespace.Properties.Settings"); // This is the section name, change to your needs
var setting = section.Settings.Get("connectionStringKey "); // This is the setting name, change to your needs
return setting.Value.ValueXml.InnerText;
```